# sbt scala tutorial for plugin tutorial is not adding in the grizzled plugin correctly

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-plugin

I'm trying to follow the steps listed here

https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Plugins.html#Using+a+library+in+a+build+definition+example

so I have `project/plugins.sbt`, (I changed this line b/c the original line wasn't installing due to prob the scala version mismatch)

```scala
// my line
libraryDependencies += "org.clapper" % "grizzled-scala_2.8.1" % "1.0.4"

// original line
libraryDependencies += "org.clapper" %% "grizzled-scala" % "1.0.4"
```

So now when I open my SBt, it appears to have pulled in the correct lib, but when I run `sbt plugins`, nothing shows up pertaining to Grizzled.

so When I eventually try to run `sbt > eval grizzled.sys.os`

I run into this problem:

[image]

I'm running 2.13.latest in the host project, What am I missing?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what are you trying to do. Do you want to create a sbt plugin? Are you trying to use a plugin in your project? Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I'm trying to "use a plugin in the project", isn't hat what the documentation is suggesting?

Comment: If you want to [use a plugin in your project](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Plugins.html#Using+an+auto+plugin), you have to add `addSbtPlugin(...)` in your `project/plugins.sbt` file. The link you shared in your question points to [how to add a dependency library to the custom plugin that you are building](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Plugins.html#Using+a+library+in+a+build+definition+example). [grizzled-scala](https://github.com/bmc/grizzled-scala) is a library that you can add as a dependency in your project, it's not a plugin.

Comment: ok, in that case is the documentation off by saying put it in a `project/plugins.sbt`? and also why does it say `reload plugins` after the change?

Comment: your application can depends on a third-party library. In the build definition file (`build.sbt`) you can set dependencies for the project with `libraryDependencies`. Also you can use a third-party library to be used in your build definition adding that dependency in the `project/plugins.sbt`. In the section [Using an auto plguin](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Plugins.html#Using+an+auto+plugin) you can see in the example that a library is bein added as a depedency with the comment `// plain library (not an sbt plugin) for use in the build definition`.

Comment: So, the section [Using a library in a build definition example](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Plugins.html#Using+a+library+in+a+build+definition+example), shows how to use a library in your build definition (`build.sbt`) instead of make your project have that library as a depdency. The `reload` is to avoid exit the sbt console and load everything again. If you change some file in your project, executing `reload` will refresh what was loaded when you run `sbt`

Comment: what's the difference between definining a libraryDepenency in the build.sbt vs plugins.sbt? Also it doesn't just say `reload`, it says `reload plugins`

Comment: I think this is being extended without getting anywhere. We should avoid long discussions in comments. Please edit your post asking a specific question about the issue you have. Create one post per question

Comment: I'm happy to cut this into a separate post or thread if the original issue can be resolved, I can select your response if you think you may have the solution. So how do I run `eval grizzled.sys.os` successfully like the instructions under: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Plugins.html#2%29+Use+the+library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [sbt](https://www.scala-sbt.org/) you have:

- [Build definition](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Basic-Def.html):

> #### What is a build definition?
>
> A build definition is defined in `build.sbt`, and it consists of a set of projects (of type [Project](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/api/sbt/Project.html)). Because the term project can be ambiguous, we often call it a subproject in this guide.

- [Plugins](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Plugins.html)

> #### What is a Plugin?
>
> A plugin is a way to use external code in a build definition. A plugin can be a library used to implement a task (you might use [Knockoff](https://github.com/tristanjuricek/knockoff/) to write a markdown processing task). A plugin can define a sequence of sbt settings that are automatically added to all projects or that are explicitly declared for selected projects. For example, a plugin might add a proguard task and associated (overridable) settings. Finally, a plugin can define new commands (via the commands setting).

---

In `build.sbt` you are going to declare the definition of your project (or [multiple projects](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html)). You can set different *attributes* of your project such as the **scala version**, **name of the project**, **authors**, **license**, etc. Also you can define all the **libraries** that are required to build the project you define.

Let's say that we want to create a project named `hello-sbt`, organization name `Hello LLC`, scala version `2.13.11` and [scalatest](https://www.scalatest.org/) as one of the dependency libraries. Our `build.sbt` should look like

```scala
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "hello-sbt",
    organizationName := "Hello LLC"
    scalaVersion := "2.13.11",
    libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.16" % Test
  )
```

Doing this, will allow us to put some scala files in `src/main/scala` and also execute them with the command `sbt run` (mean while there is a [main method](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/hello-world-1.html) or the [App trait is bein mixed](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/hello-world-2.html)). Also we will be able to execute the command `sbt test` because we are using a testing library (in this case `scalatest`) that will execute all the test we put in `src/test/scala`.

Lets say that now we want to add an sbt plugin to our project, for example [wartremover](https://github.com/wartremover/wartremover) (it is a flexible Scala code linting tool). To install it, we only need to create a file named `plugins.sbt` inside the directory `project` and only add the following line

```scala
addSbtPlugin("org.wartremover" % "sbt-wartremover" % "3.1.3")
```

Just doing that we can use it in our `build.sbt` as it is detailed in the doc that explain [how to install and setup](https://www.wartremover.org/doc/install-setup.html).

---

In the case of [grizzled-scala](http://software.clapper.org/grizzled-scala/), it's **not** a **sbt plugin**, it's a **library**. If we want to have that library available to be used in our build definition, adding as a dependency library of our project like this

```scala
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "hello-sbt",
    organizationName := "Hello LLC"
    scalaVersion := "2.13.11",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.clapper" %% "grizzled-scala" % "4.10.0",
      "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.16" % Test
    )
  )
```

will let us use the library as a dependency of the project, but not in the build definition. To [use the library in the build definition file](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Plugins.html#Using+a+library+in+a+build+definition+example), you have to add it as a dependency but in the `project/plugins.sbt` file. Following the previous example I gave, the file with grizzled addded as dependency should look like

```scala
addSbtPlugin("org.wartremover" % "sbt-wartremover" % "3.1.3")
libraryDependencies += "org.clapper" %% "grizzled-scala" % "4.10.0"
```

Once this is done, you can use the library in your `build.sbt`. For example, we can [Define a new Task](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Tasks.html) named `printOperativeSystem` that prints the name of the operative system that we are using. Now our `build.sbt` will look like

```scala
import grizzled.sys.os

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "hello-sbt",
    organizationName := "Hello LLC"
    scalaVersion := "2.13.11",
    libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.16" % Test
  )

lazy val printOperativeSystem = taskKey[Unit]("Prints the name of the Operative System using grizzled library")
printOperativeSystem := println(os.name)
```

With this, we have a new task `printOperativeSystem` that we can execute from the command line

```bash
> sbt printOperativeSystem
Mac OS
```

Or you can try to run `eval grizzled.sys.os` as it is showed in the [docs](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Plugins.html#2%29+Use+the+library) you are following

---

As a side note, I used [grizzled-scala](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.clapper/grizzled-scala) `4.10.0` because `1.0.4` is only released for scala `2.8.0` and `2.8.1`. I think that could be the root cause of your problem. Also the error message you are receiving suggest to check version conflict. Remember that sbt is built on top of `scala 2.12`

Comment: worked! tysm! I think you should update their official sbt docs as that appears to be out of date.